# How to active a checkbox when clicking anywhere within the same row?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes. If I click on any checkbox it works great, but how can allow the user to activate a checkbox when **clicking anywhere in the same** row and not just the specific checkbox?

```
 return(
       <div
         key={idx}
         style={{
           background: "yellow",
           borderBottom: "1px solid #ccc",
           width: 150
         }}
         >
         <input
           type="checkbox"
           checked={isChecked}
           onChange={(e) =>
            handleCheckboxChange(field, e.target.checked)
           }
         />
         <span>{field?.name}</span>
         <br />
       </div>
     );
```

Comment: Replace the `<div>` wrapper with `<label>`. And add `display: block` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow the user to activate a checkbox when clicking anywhere within the same row, you need to adjust your code to wrap each row's content in a `<label>` element. The `<label>` element associates a label with an input element (in this case, a checkbox). When you click on the label, it toggles the associated checkbox.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this behavior:

```
jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Post = ({ post, checkboxStates, setCheckboxStates }) => {
  const [showGroup, setShowGroup] = useState(true);

  const handleCheckboxChange = (field, isChecked) => {
    const key = `${post.label}_${field.name}`;
    setCheckboxStates((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [key]: isChecked
    }));
  };

  return (
    <article>
      <h2>
        {post.label}{" "}
        <span onClick={() => setShowGroup(!showGroup)}>
          {showGroup ? "-" : "+"}
        </span>
      </h2>
      {showGroup && (
        <div>
          {post.fields?.map((field: any, idx: number) => {
            const key = `${post.label}_${field.name}`;
            const isChecked = checkboxStates[key] || false;
            return (
              <div
                key={idx}
                style={{
                  background: "yellow",
                  borderBottom: "1px solid #ccc",
                  width: 150
                }}
              >
                <label>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={isChecked}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      handleCheckboxChange(field, e.target.checked)
                    }
                  />
                  <span>{field?.name}</span>
                </label>
                <br />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </article>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

By wrapping each checkbox and its associated text in a `<label>` element, clicking anywhere within the row (including the text) will activate the checkbox. This is a good practice for improving the user experience and accessibility of your checkboxes.

Comment: @Devmix that's a styling thing and you should be able to fix it by just expanding the label , probably by defining it as `display: block`

Comment: To have the label fill the row, use `label {width: 100%; display: inline-block;}` @Devmix